# How to show that $x^2\equiv 2 \pmod {11}$ has no solution.

Tags: number-theory

I am not familiar with the topic. I can work out for the problem when the problem has a solution. But here I don't know how to it. Using the table I can see there is no solution. But I want to know how to do mathematically.

Comment: Compute $x^2 \textrm{ mod } 11$ for $x=0,1,\dots,10$. I think this approach is "mathematical".

Comment: I think by, "I want to know how to do mathematically", you really mean, "I want to know how to do it without using the table"...

Comment: Checking all 11 possible values of $x$ is a perfectly mathematical way of doing this.

Comment: @azif00 You can save one $x$ or six $x$'s.

Comment: No other way???

Comment: One "other way" is to say that $11 \equiv 3\mod 8$. Another "other way" is to say that $2 \equiv -3^2 \mod 11$ and $11 \equiv 3 \mod 4$.

Comment: There is a general theorem that, for odd primes $p,$ $x^2\equiv 2\pmod p$ has a solution if and only if $p\equiv \pm  1\pmod 8.$

Comment: @lisyarus, it only works with small modulus

Comment: @Yassir it "works" with any modulus, it's just not practical. (and, well, 11 is small enough)

Comment: @MadhanKumar you could only check $x^2\pmod{11}$ for $x=0,1,\dots,5$, since $x^2\equiv(-x)^2\pmod{11}$.

Comment: In general, for prime $p,$ and any $n$ not divisible by $p$ $x^2\equiv n\pmod p$ has a solution if and only if $n^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod p.$ Here, $n=2,p=11,$ then $2^5=32\not\equiv 1\pmod{11}.$

Comment: If you want you can try "my beginner method". $x=11k±1,±2,±3,±4±5$ it doesn't require more time. At most 2 minutes. You can prove.

Comment: Apply **Euler's Criterion**, i.e. raise $\,x^2\equiv 2\,$  to power $\, (p-1)/2 = 5\,$ to get $\,x^{10}\equiv -1,\,$ contra lil Fermat, as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260002/242) in the 2nd dupe.

Comment: I think it's better and "more mathematical" to hit a problem with a rook a bunch of times then to go to the deep end of the pool, borrow a magic formula you don't understand and try to apply it. Work your way to understanding the method Thomas Andrews and Bill Dubuque suggest (they are both *excellent* suggestions) but play with taking the $11$ possible classes of $x$ ans squaring them and seeing what you get until you start *feeling* things.