# Proving that $(x-2)^3 = 3 \text{ mod 13}$ admits no solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I wish to prove that $(x-2)^3 = 3 \text{ mod 13}$  admits no solutions. Admittedly, I could always plug in the numbers $0, 1, 2, ..., 12$ and show that for each of them $(x-2)^3$ is not congruent to $3$, but I would wish for a cleverer method than this...

I have thought of showing (*if* this indeed sufficient) that $3 + 13k$ can never be written as a perfect cube.

Comment: your second paragraph works. Just find the cubes $\pmod {13}.$  Like this: $1^3 = 1.$   $ 2^3 = 8. $  and so on

Comment: @WillJagy Is the best method to show that the only possible residues of cubes modulo 13 are 0, 1, 8 by checking every number between 0 and 12?

Comment: @V.Elizabeth:  you missed some cubes, e.g., $4^3$ and $7^3$

Comment: Adding on to @WillJagy's comment, you can cut your work in half by noting $(-x)^3=-x^3$ so you only have to check the residues up to $6$. The others will give you the negatives of what you get from $0,\ldots,6$.

Comment: V.E.  it really would be a good thing if you found the cubes mod 13. For example, $ 3^3 = 27 = 26 + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod {13}.$  We can reduce at each stage:  $5^2 = 25 \equiv -1 \pmod {13}$ so that $5^3 \equiv -1 \cdot 5 = -5 \equiv 8 \pmod {13}$

Comment: Applying *Euler's Criterion* as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1260002/242) in the dupe: $\bmod 13\!:\ \left[a^3\equiv 3\right ]^4\Rightarrow 1\equiv 3\Rightarrow 13\mid 2\Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another, I believe easier, way. We have

$$((x-2)^3)^4 \equiv 3^4 \pmod{13} \;\;\to\;\; (x-2)^{12} \equiv 81 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$$

However, since $x-2 \not\equiv 0\pmod{13}$, then [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) gives that $(x-2)^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$, contradicting the above equation.

An alternate, although similar, method is to note that $(x-2)^6 \equiv 3^2 \equiv 9 \pmod{13}$, but $(x-2)^6 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{13}$ (using that $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv \pm 1\pmod{p}$ for $a \not\equiv 0\pmod{p}$), so once again we get a contradiction.

Comment: *Please* strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

We can ask the simpler question does there exist an $x$ such that $x^3\equiv 3 \pmod {13}.$  (expecting that no such number will exist.

$2$ generates the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_{13}^\times$... that is all numbers (other than zero) can be represented as $2^k$

But $2^{3k} \equiv \{8,12,5,1\}$ and $3$ is not in that set.

Comment: I think you mean that $2$ is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) modulo $13$

Comment: i.e., $2$ is a generator of the multiplicative group modulo $13$, which excludes $0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks for the input.  I have made a small correction.  Do you think that that is adequately precise?

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).