# Is it necessary for a number of the form $4k^2+1$ to have at least one prime factor of the form $4n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

> Is it necessary for a number of the form $4k^2+1$ to have at least one prime factor of the form $4n+1$?

I was trying to prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4n+1$, but to prove it, I need to prove the above statement true.

Comment: Even more : EVERY prime factor of such a number must be of the form $4n+1$

Comment: @Peter I would really appreciate if you provide a proof for that.

Comment: Considering quadratic residues, the proof is trivial. Every prime factor $p$ must be odd, and since the number is of the form $n^2+1$ , $-1$ is a so-called quadratic residue mod $p$ , whenever $p$ divides $4k^2+1$ , we can conclude immediately that $p$ must be congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: Cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142007/prove-that-x2-equiv-1-mod-p-has-no-solutions-if-prime-p-equiv-3-pmo)

Comment: Also there are infinitely many primes of the form $4n+1$ trivially by Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions.