# Wilson's Theorem and quadratic Congruence $x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Using Wilson's theorem, we show that if $p$ is an odd prime $x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has a solution if and only if $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ . Why cant $p$ be of the form $4n+3$ ?

Comment: $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$ , if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$. Hence such a prime cannot divide a number of the form $x^2+1$ with integer $x$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I am sorry , I didn't get ** -1 is not quadratic residue modulo p ** part

Comment: That is only another formulation of "$x^2\equiv -1\mod p$ has no solution".

Comment: Thank you ! got answer here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142007/prove-that-x2-equiv-1-pmod-p-has-no-solutions-if-prime-p-equiv-3-pmod)

Comment: If $p\equiv3\pmod4$ then $p-1$ is not divisible by four. Therefore there cannot be an element of order four in the group $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ for that would violate Lagrange's theorem.