# $-1$ isn't a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}, p=4k+3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I remember coming across this fact a while ago in a pdf somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it again. Can someone show me how to prove it? I would appreciate easier proofs.

EDIT: I'm very sorry, I forgot to actually state it.

Prove that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo primes of the form $4k+3$.

Thanks!

Comment: This depends on how much you already know. It follows from the more general statement $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\pmod {p}, \forall a\in\mathbb Z, p$ an odd prime.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done fractions in modular arithmetic yet. Is it possible to explain/refer to where I can learn about them? Thanks!

Comment: I was referring to [the Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

Comment: @user314: Thanks, I'll try to understand it.

Comment: Understanding the proof of my statement is not elementary. At least the proof I know requires knowing about [primitive roots modulo primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) and knowing that $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\left(\frac{b}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{ab}{p}\right), \forall$ primes $p$.

Comment: @user314: Ok, cheers. Do you recommend any number theory books? I've been looking to buy one for a while. My friend said Burton's Elementary Number Theory is good for beginners.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really know much about English books. I use a book in my own language. I've heard that "Introduction to Number Theory" by Hua Loo Keng is great, but I can't tell you much. If you haven't heard about it, Engel's "Problem Solving Strategies" is very popular among those studying for Math olympiads.

Comment: @user314: Thanks a lot, problem solving strategies one sounds good!

Answer (score 4):

$x^2=-1$ holds if and only if $x$ has order $4$. An element of order $4$ exists in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^* \cong C_{p-1}$ if and only if $4|p-1$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand the notation nearing the end of the proof. Also I'm not asking about $x^2=-1$ but $x^2\equiv -1$. (I apologize if I misunderstood anything)

Comment: $C_{p-1}$ is the cyclic group with $p-1$ elements. When i write $x^2=-1$, I interpret this as an eqauality in the ring $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. This the same as the $\equiv$-notation.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\  \overbrace{{\rm mod}\ P=4K\!+\!3\!:}^{\large\ \ \ \  P\ -\ 1\,\ =\,\ 2(\color{#c00}{2K+1})}\,\ \ X^{\large 2}\equiv -1\!\!\!\!\!\!\overset{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\ \  )^{\Large\color{#c00}{2K+1}}}\Longrightarrow\! X^{\large P\,-\,1}\equiv -1\ $ contra little Fermat

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4872/242) for much further discussion, e.g. group-theoretic viewpoints.