# $x^{2} \equiv-1\ \pmod p$ has a solution if and only if $p\equiv 1\ \pmod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

If $p$ is a prime. Then $x^{2} \equiv-1\ \pmod p$ has a solution if and only if $p\equiv 1\ \pmod 4$. Please explain in the easiest way.

Comment: Counterexample: 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean odd primes.

If $$p \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow \left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p (\because \text{Wilson's Theorem})$$ So we have shown that if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ exists.

Now let us show that if $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$, then $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. If $$x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p \Rightarrow (x^2)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod p $$ By Fermat's Little Theorem.

Thus we have $\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod 2$, and $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Is this special case of Wilson's theorem?

Comment: @Ayushakj That depends on how you define "special case", but $$\left(\left(\frac{p-1}{2}\right)!\right)^2 \equiv (-1)^{\frac{p+1}{2}} \pmod p $$ using $-x \equiv p-x \pmod p$.

Comment: @Ayushakj fixed.

Comment: how u got: $\frac{p-1}{2} \equiv 0 \pmod 2$

Comment: @Ayushakj $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple proof using group theory and the fact that $U(p)$ is cyclic. Assume $p$ is odd.

$x^{2} \equiv-1 \bmod p$ has a solution if and only if $U(p)$ has an element of order $4$.

Since $U(p)$ is a cyclic group, this happens iff $4$ divides the order of $U(p)$, which is $p-1$.

Comment: [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/4872/242) for much more on the group theory behind it.