# Uniqueness of $k$th root mod $m$ if $(k, \phi(m)) = 1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I'm trying to prove a fact about $k$th roots that says that if $(k, \phi(m)) = 1$ and $(b,m) = 1$, then there is a unique $k$th root modulo $m$ (composite $m$).

I'm not sure how to go about it but here's an attempt;

Suppose towards a contradiction that there are two solutions $x_1 = b^r$ and $x_2 = b^s$ to the congruence $x^k \equiv b \bmod m$. Then $$x_1^k \equiv x_2^k \equiv b \bmod m$$

so that $b^{kr} \equiv b^{ks} \equiv b \bmod m$, or equivalently, $b^{kr - 1} \equiv b^{ks - 1} \bmod m$. We can then conclude that $m \mid b^{kr - 1} - b^{ks - 1}$. Now we can factor to obtain $b^{kr - 1} - b^{ks - 1} = b^{kr - 1}(b^{k(s-r)} - 1)$ to conclude that $m \mid b^{kr - 1}(b^{k(s-r)} - 1)$. But since $(b, m) = 1$, we must have $m\mid b^{k(s-r)} - 1$, or equivalently,

$$b^{k(s-r)} \equiv 1 \bmod m$$

which would imply $k(s-r) = \phi(m)v$ for some $v \in \mathbb Z$.

I feel like there could be a way to extract a contradiction from this last step but I can't see it, would somebody be able to check if this is a good way to go?

Comment: Why do you presume that the solutions are powers of $b?\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm not sure, I think just because the algorithm described in the textbook I'm using takes $x = b^u$ as a solution, with $ku - \phi(m)v = 1$.

Comment: The textbook is probably using something similar to the methods in the answers below. If your proof is a continuation of the textbook proof then it is essential that you supply the initial parts of the proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque The textbook provides no proof, it's an exercise at the end of the chapter so I'm simply guessing that $x$ is a power of $b$ in the same way that the algorithm described says that $x$ is a power $b$, if that helps.

Comment: What precisely is the algorithm described in the textbook?

Comment: @BillDubuque Compute $\phi(m)$, find positive integers $u, v$ such that $ku - \phi(m)v = 1$, compute $b^u \bmod m.$ This is a solution to the congruence $x^k \equiv b \bmod m$, since $x^k \equiv b^{uk} \equiv b^{1 + \phi(m)v} \equiv b \bmod m$ by Euler's formula.

Comment: i.e. $\! \bmod{\phi}\!:\,\ ku\equiv 1,\,$ so $\,u\equiv 1/k.\,$ This is the same idea used in all the answers below. In my answer I tried to make it explict how it amounts to taking $k$'th roots - which is the same as taking a $u$'th power, since the "fraction" $1/k := k^{-1}$ is congruent to the *integer* $\,u\pmod{\phi}\ \ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach:

Since $(k, \phi(m)) = 1$, write $uk + v \phi(m)=1$ for $u,v \in \mathbb Z$.

Then, if $(x,m)=1$ we have $x=x^1=x^{uk + v \phi(m)}={(x^u)}^k (x^{\phi(m)})^v \equiv {(x^u)}^k \bmod m$.

This proves that the map $x \mapsto x^k$ is surjective and so is a bijection.

In other words, every $x$ with $(x,m)=1$ has a unique $k$-th root mod $m$.

Answer (score 3):

To (uniquely) solve $\ x^{\large k} \equiv b\ $ take a $k$'th root (i.e. raise both sides to power $1/k)$,  just as for reals.

Let $\phi = \phi(m).\, $ $\,(k,\phi) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, j := 1/k\pmod{\!\phi}\,$ exists, so raising to power $\,j\,$ yields

$$\begin{align} &\left[x_1^{\large k} \equiv b\equiv x_2^{\large k}\right]^{\large j}\\
\Rightarrow\ &\ \  x_1 \equiv b^{\large j}\!\equiv x_2\end{align}$$

This works because by Euler all exponents can be taken mod $\phi$ (on all  $\,a\,$ coprime to $m),\,$ i.e. $\!\bmod m\!:\ \color{#c00}{a^{\large \phi}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large r+q\,\phi}\equiv a^{\large r}(\color{#c00}{a^{\large \phi}})^{\large q}\equiv a^{\large r}\color{#c00}1^{\large q}\equiv a^{\large r},\ $ i.e. $\,a^{\large n}\!\equiv a^{\large n\bmod\phi},\,$ hence
$$ (x^{\large k})^{\large j}\! \equiv x^{\large kj}\!\equiv x^{\large kj\bmod\phi}\!\equiv x^{\large k(1/k)\bmod \phi}\!\equiv x^{\large 1}$$  Thus the solution amounts to raising $\,x^{\large k}\,$ to power $\,1/k\,$ (i.e. taking its $k$'th root) to solve for $\,x.$

Note: it is valid to apply Euler $\phi\,$ to powers of $x$ since $\,(x,m) = 1,\,$ by $\,1=(b,m)=(x^k,m)$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188192/242) for elaboration and a fully worked example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed alone to get to the statement that $k(s-r) = \phi(m)v$ for some $v \in \Bbb Z$. From this I can deduce that $s-r = \phi(m)u$ for some $u \in \Bbb Z$ so that $b^{s-r} \equiv 1 \bmod m$ and so that $x_1 \equiv x_2 \bmod m$, contradicting the original assumption. Is this in any way logically flawed or does this work to show that the congruence has a unique solution? Not to disregard your answer, I'd just also like to have my own proof verified! :)

Comment: Ok so in my case I've got $k=2019$ but the answer is not $b^{1/2019} (\text{mod} \ p)$ but rather $b^\alpha \ (\text{mod} \ p)$ according to my original thread. Also, you use $\phi$, which I assume is Eulers totient function? But totient function of what? Why is this true: $\,(k,\phi) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, j := 1/k\,$ exists $\!\pmod{\!\phi}\ \ ?$ I really can't seem to grasp how to apply this to my problem.

Comment: @Parseval As above, $\ j = 1/k\bmod \phi = 1/2019\bmod p\!-\!1,\,$ by $\,\phi(p) = p\!-\!1.\,$  Recall by Bezout $\,\gcd(k,\phi) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, \exists\,j,n\!:\  jk+n\phi = 1\,\Rightarrow\bmod \phi\!:\ jk\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, j\equiv 1/k.\,$

Comment: @BillDubuque - Ok I think I'm starting to get things now. I only need further elaboration on the part where you write "...all exponents can be taken mod $\phi$..." and how you from that conclude that $a^n\equiv a^{n \ \text{mod} \ \phi}$.

Comment: @Parseval That's what we prove in the subsequent equations: i.e. if $\,a^{\large \phi}\equiv 1\pmod{\!m}\,$ then $\,n\equiv r\pmod{\!\phi}\,\Rightarrow$  $\,a^{\large n}\equiv a^{\large r}\pmod{\!m}.\,$ In particular that holds when $\,r = (n\bmod \phi).\ $

Answer (score 2):

There is $l$ with $kl\equiv 1\pmod{\phi(m)}$. Note that for all $a$
coprime to $m$, then $r\equiv s\pmod{\phi(m)}$ implies $a^r\equiv a^s\pmod m$.

Then $$b\equiv a^k\pmod{m}\iff a\equiv b^l\pmod{m}.$$
One way: $b\equiv a^k\pmod{m}\implies b^l\equiv a^{kl}\pmod m$.
As $a^{kl}\equiv a\pmod{m}$ (why?) that does it.
Other way: similar.