# Modular Exponentiation Bijection Crtieria

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it true that for
$$ f(x) = x^e\:mod\:m$$

$f$ is bijective and not the identify function if and only if

1. $m$ is the product of unique primes
2. For each prime factor of $m$ called $p$, $e$ is coprime to $p-1$
3. Given $l=lcm(\{p_i-1\})$ (the smallest number which is a multiple of each factor of m) $e \neq 1\:mod\:l$

I've tried it for all combinations of e and m up to 500 and it appears to hold in those cases.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2385495/242).

Comment: I'm not quite following.  I can see that showing that f is bijective is equivalent to showing that for all x<m: f(x) has unique eth roots mod m, however proving that part is not the part I'm having trouble with.  I'm fairly sure that my criteria makes f bijective but I'm having trouble proving that it's necessary.  It seems like the statement they're trying to prove would be really useful if it worked in the other direction.