# Solve $n^2 \equiv -1 \mod 4m+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The following equation has no solution for $m<1000$ (see computation below)  $$n^2 \equiv -1 \mod 4m+3 $$

*Question*: Is there a solution in general?

---

```
sage: for k in range(1000):
....:     for n in range(4*k+3):
....:         if (n**2+1).mod(4*k+3)==0:
....:             print([k,n])
....:
sage:
```

Comment: I see no reason to delete the post. Further, at least some users have valued the other answer, and we very rarely delete upvoted content without good reason.

Comment: Improved question: [Numbers $m$ such that $\sqrt{-1}$ mod $m$ exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2962114/84284)

Comment: See also [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872/group-theory-proof-of-existence-of-a-solution-to-x2-equiv-1-pmod-p-iff-p-eq/4878#4878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation has no solution.

*Proof*:   First assume that $4m+3$ is a prime number $p$. By [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) we have:
$$ n^2 \equiv -1 \mod p \  \  \Rightarrow  \ \ (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \mod p.$$
But $\frac{p-1}{2} = 2m+1$, so $-1 = (-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \mod p$, contradiction with $p$ odd.

Now if $4m+3$ is composite, let $q$ any prime factor. Then $$ n^2 \equiv -1 \mod q$$ but $q$ is odd and by the first part $q \not \equiv 3 \mod 4$, so $q \equiv 1 \mod 4$. It follows that $$3 \equiv 4m+3 \equiv 1^{r} \equiv 1\mod 4$$ with $r$ the number of prime factors of $4m+3$ (with multiplicity), contradiction. $\square$

Answer (score 3):

Shorter version of the other answer:

$4m+3$ must have at least one prime factor $p$ of the form $p = 4k+3$. Reducing modulo $p$, the equation reads $n^2\equiv -1\pmod p$, which is impossible by [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).